# instanceof with an interface

Tags: java, instanceof

If I try to use instanceof  operator with wrong class I'm getting a compile error (" Animal can not be converted to String")  but with an interface I'm not getting compile time error.

For eg:  In line 10 I'm getting a compile error because Animal is not a subclass of String. But in line 14 I'm not getting a compile error even though Animal does not implement List interface.

```
class Animal {

}

public class InstanceOf {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Animal a = new Animal();
        if (a instanceof String ){  //line 10
            System.out.println("True");
        }

         if (a instanceof List ){ //line 14
            System.out.println("True");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please include the exact error message in the question.

Comment: Consider this: `class B extends Animal implements List`. Now this: `Animal a = new B();`

Comment: @Tunaki You also have the "Dupehammer®" - why didn't you close it? (Likely: You are as hesitant as me ... :-/ )

Comment: @Marco13 Nope, was simply out of votes for yesterday :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`a` can never be an instanceof String, hence the compilation error.

`a` can be an instance of `List` if some sub-class of `Animal` would implement the `List` interface and you would assign an instance of such sub-class to `a`. Therefore the compiler allows it.

From the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) :

> If a cast (§15.16) of the RelationalExpression to the ReferenceType would be rejected as a compile-time error, then the instanceof relational expression likewise produces a compile-time error. In such a situation, the result of the instanceof expression could never be true.

Comment: Is java not allowed multiple inheritance is the root cause? At the same time any subclass can implement an Interface whenever it wants?

Comment: @nantitv Yes. Since Animal is not a sub-class of String, any sub-class of Animal cannot be a sub-class of String. Though in your specific snippet, it wouldn't make a difference even if multiple inheritance was allowed, since String is final and cannot be sub-classed.

Comment: Thanks . String I just took it for an example.

Comment: @nantitv if you tell the compiler that there will be no subclasses of `Animal`, it will in fact be able to infer that `instanceof` is pointless: simply replace `class Animal{}` by `final class Animal{}`.

Answer (score 2):

Just an experiment I did from this question.

```
class Animal {}
interface AnimalA {}
class AnimalB{} 

class AnimalC extends Animal,AnimalB {} //not possible
class AnimalD extends Animal implements AnimalA{} //possible   

public class InstanceOfTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal a = new Animal();
        if(a instanceof AnimalA) { //no compile time error
            System.out.println("interface test");
        }
        if(a instanceof AnimalB) { //compile time error
            System.out.println("interface test");
        }
        if(a instanceof List) { //compile time error
            System.out.println("interface test");
        }
        if(a instanceof ArrayList) { //compile time error
            System.out.println("interface test");
        }
    }
}
```

So as @Eran said, as `Animal` is not a sub-class of `AnimalB` non of its sub-class can become and instance of `AnimalB`. But on the other any of its sub-class can implement `interface` List.